# gatsby-source-contentful options error on build

Tags: deployment, gatsby, netlify, contentful

some time back I made a site with Gatsby and I've used static markdown for my pages.
Now I wanted to move all my posts on Contentful and everything works fine in development. 
When I went on Netlify to deploy my website it threw me an error. 
I've looked for solutions but haven't found one yet. 
I tried to run the build locally and it throws me this error, so I believe I need to fix this first before deploying.

```
ERROR 

Problems with gatsby-source-contentful plugin options:
spaceId: undefined - "spaceId" is required
accessToken: undefined - "accessToken" is required
host (default value): "cdn.contentful.com"
environment (default value): "master"
downloadLocal (default value): false
localeFilter (default value): [Function]
forceFullSync (default value): false
pageLimit (default value): 100
useNameForId (default value): true

not finished onPreBootstrap - 0.056s
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! gatsby-starter-hello-world@0.1.0 build: `gatsby build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the gatsby-starter-hello-world@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-13T15_20_35_160Z-debug.log
```

Apparently it does not read the .env variables. I do have the variables set on Netlify and as I said earlier on development it works just fine without throwing any kind of error.

I did not have 'dotenv' installed before and tried to install it but did not solve the issue. 
I do have only one '.env' file, but have tried to make '.env.development' and '.env.production' files but did not work.

How can I fix the problem?
As an extra I do get some errors, on Netlify only, such as

```
error There was an error in your GraphQL query:
Unknown type "ContentfulFluid".
```

but I do not think they cause the build to fail.

EDIT:
I should add that if I do write the .env variables as strings the build does run locally, which makes me believe it would do on deployment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set your `.env` variables in Netlify with `GATSBY_` prefix. So, your `CONTENTFUL_ID` variable will be `GATSBY_CONTENTFUL_ID`.

[image]

It's recommended to use the same naming in your local and build environment to keep the logic between them. So, you will need to prefix all references to `.env` using `GATSBY_` in your local environment too. To do this, you may need to create a `.env.development` and `.env.production` if you haven't set it before.

You can check for further information in [Netlify documentation](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/common-configurations/#gatsby):

> **Gatsby environment variables**
>
> Any environment variables prefixed with `GATSBY_` will be processed by
>   Gatsby and made available in the browser for client-side JavaScript
>   access. Visit the Gatsby docs about environment variables for more
>   information.

As well as in [Gatsby's documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/environment-variables/#example-of-using-an-environment-variable).

Comment: After making those changes it still throws me the same error of spaceId and accessToken being undefined, both locally and on deployment.
For clarity I did edit my CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID to GATSBY_CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID trying not/and changing the references in the code to env.GAT.. but nothing seems to change

Comment: Try to trigger a manual deploy cleaning the cache. Also, just to reassure. You `gatsby-config.js` has the correct variables, isn't?

Comment: Tried multiple times to trigger a deploy that way but is not solving the issue.
Also, yes, I can confirm the `gatsby-config.js` has `process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID`, and so, on set.

Comment: Change `process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID` to `process.env.GATSBY_CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID`

Comment: All environment variables must have the same naming. Once you've set them in Netlify, you need to change it locally. If your `.env.development` has the variable without `GATSBY_` prefix, of course, it will fail.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213798/discussion-between-ferran-buireu-and-john).

Answer (score 1):

After many attempts trying to debug my code and installing previous versions of `gatsby-source-contentful` I found out that you would get an error if you have no `Media` on `contentful`.
To fix any similar error all you need to do is add a dummy media on `contentful` itself and it would work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

In the environment variable **.env.development** you need to add

```
CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID = <Paste here your space Id>
CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN = <Paste here your delivery API - access token>
```